# localStorage no funciona

Tags: javascript, local-storage, theme

Tengo una aplicación a la cual le quiero agregar un dark mode. Agregué un botón que cambia los estilos y este funciona correctamente. El problema que no he podido resolver es que cuando quiero guardar los cambios en el storage no funciona con el primer clic. Es decir la primera vez que clickeo para que cambie de modo claro a oscuro no guarda el par clave/valor en el localStorage. Entonces en el primer clic no pasa nada, ya en el segundo clic (en el que vuelve a poner la pantalla clara) ahí si empieza a funcionar pero guarda el par ("theme", "dark"), entonces guarda al revés de lo que necesito. Porque cuando recargo la página cuando esta se debería ver con los estilos del dark mode se recarga en modo ligth y viceversa. Espero haberme explicado de manera correcta para que se entienda. a continuación el código:

```
const d = document;
const $darkBtn = d.querySelector('.dark'),
 $ligthBtn = d.querySelector('.ligth');

export default function darkMode(btn, theme){
    let local = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if(local === 'dark') d.documentElement.classList.add(theme)
    d.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        if(e.target.matches(btn) || e.target.matches(`${btn} *`)){
            if(e.target.classList.contains('dark') || e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('dark')){
                $darkBtn.style.display = 'none';
                $ligthBtn.style.display = 'block';
                
                d.documentElement.classList.toggle(theme);
                /* localStorage.clear() */
                localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark')
            }
            if(e.target.classList.contains('ligth') || e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('ligth')){
                
                $darkBtn.style.display = 'block';
                $ligthBtn.style.display = 'none';
            
                document.documentElement.classList.toggle(theme);
            
                localStorage.setItem('theme', 'ligth')
            }
        }   
    })
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuando se ejecuta la función darkMode()?

Comment: Cuando se carga el documento. Esta se encuentra en un modulo y la llamo desde el archivo ppal (index.js)

Comment: Por cierto, `ligth` normalmente se escribe `light`

Comment: Puedes subir el html?, por favor si no es mucha molestia.

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux perdón que recién conteste, es que entré a trabajar. Cuando vuelva al proyecto lo subo